# pre_get_posts conflict with archive posts

Tags: archives, bbpress

Currently using bbPress as a forum. But now I have some conflict and archive post page is displaying instead of forum? How should I proceed? Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Actually found the causing problem. It is that function that seems is interupting somehow with my forums. The function is for displaying custom post type in author archive page. Still don't have a solution for that problem.

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_archive() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'vehicles'
      ));
     return $query;
   }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

Comment: Currently don't have a solution. I'm asking how this function interupts my forums and a idea how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the post again. I found the problem, but didn't found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) function stands, you'll have that conflict as you are using `pre_get_posts` very carelessly.

`pre_get_posts` modifies the query variable object before the main query **AND** `WP_Query` is executed. So any changes in your function will influence both the main query and any custom query that uses `WP_Query`. That is why everything is haywire in your forum pages as well, as you are adding these changes to your forum as well

Secondly, when working with any type of archive query (`is_archive()`, `is_category()` etc), any changes made with `pre_get_posts` will also affect the back end

So, your solution would be to run `pre_get_posts` only on the main query (`is_main_query()`), and also just in the front end (`!is_admin()`)

Something like this will do

```
if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive() );
```

**EDIT**

I'm not going to change my code above. Only realized your code is for author page. Then you should be using `is_author()`, not `is_archive()`

Comment: Please see my edit as well. Misread author for archive

Comment: That did the job! Thanks a lot! I'll further learn more about queries. Not an easy job.